# What tool exists to easily browse, query and validate OData v4 services

Tags: gui, api

I am currently working on a new OData based API for one of my projects. I would like to have an (preferably UI based) tool which allows me to browse, test and validate the API.

A lot of people claim OData is *the best way to make RESTful APIs* but the selection of tools for working with them is terrible.

Concrete tasks I would like to fulfill with the tool:

- Validate my OData schemas / metadata
- Visualize the current data model (schema)
- Query the available entity sets with a UI query builder and grid.
- Create and modify entities provided via API

As development happens locally, the tool must be able to use local APIs.

The following tools I already evaluated:

- xodata: Looks best from the online demo, but is discontinued and not available anymore; also not free (https://pragmatiqa.com/product_xodata.html)
- OpenUI5 Odata Explorer: Has tons of dependencies that are not available in the expected structure. I tried to set it up locally but failed.  (https://github.com/hschaefer123/odataexplorer)
- Microsoft Excel: Simply claims that the metadata is not valid even though it is (no details about what is invalid).
- LinqPad with OData v4 Connection from Dmtrii Smirnov: Also complains about invalid metadata (doesn't know about NavigationProperty element which is valid).
- Postman: Only allows raw queries, no direct handling of OData requirements.

Comment: Im searching as well.
OpenUI5 Odata Explore only would support OData v2 and not v4 as you requested